# Create delta table using csv file

Tags: python

I'm trying to create delta table in databricks. I'm using [this link](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/quick-start.html) as a referrence for learning.Here it's mentioned that For all file types, I need to read the files into a DataFrame and write out in delta format:. So I wrote following code in python

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('my file path/data.csv')
df.write.format("delta").save("/mnt/delta/df")
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE df USING DELTA LOCATION '/mnt/delta/df/'")
```

But I got the error message

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Can you please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Why not dump the data directly to SQL using `df.to_sql()`?

Comment: @S3DEV, currently I don't have access to any database in databricks. So I thought to use delta table

Comment: did you find solution to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would help

```
myCSV= spark.read.csv("/path/to/input/data",header=True,sep=","); 
myCSV.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option('overwriteSchema','true').save("/mnt/delta/Employee") 
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE employee USING DELTA LOCATION '/mnt/delta/Employee/'")
```

Comment: You use spark but the initial example was with pandas. I think the initial idea was to find a solution with pandas.